# I want to initialize my observable when I get 404 response from the API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

I want to initialize my observable when  I get 404 response  from the API
I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
const urlParams = { email: this.email };
this.voicesProfileObservable$ = this.service.request<any>(
  AVAILABLE_SERVICES.GET_USER_PROFILE_VOICES.ID,
  {},
  { urlParams }
).pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    this.voicesProfileObservable$ = Observable.of({
      aboutSectionType: '',
      aboutCustomizedDescription: '',
      showSpacesFollowed: true,
      showBadgesEarned: true,
      showMobileNumber: true,
      showOfficeNumber: false,
      showEmail: true,
      showSlackHandle: false,
      video: {},
      socialLinks: [],
      personalLinks: [],
    });
    return throwError(error);
}))
```

Comment: I think this is not a valid approach ¿can you show how are you subscribing to the observable? If you subscribe to this.voicesProfileObservable$ and you assign a new observable to it, you are losing the previous reference and your subscription would be missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try it like this:

```
this.voicesProfileObservable$ = this.service.request<any>(
  AVAILABLE_SERVICES.GET_USER_PROFILE_VOICES.ID,
  {},
  { urlParams }
).pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    return of({
      aboutSectionType: '',
      aboutCustomizedDescription: '',
      showSpacesFollowed: true,
      showBadgesEarned: true,
      showMobileNumber: true,
      showOfficeNumber: false,
      showEmail: true,
      showSlackHandle: false,
      video: {},
      socialLinks: [],
      personalLinks: [],
    });
  })
)
```

You should return the default response directly inside the `catchError` callback to pass it down the subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set this.voicesProfileObservable$ more times. Once when you define and declare it as an observable, and second time you do it in catchError().

You should catch the error, and return with of(...data) without throwing the error.

```
          catchError(_ => of({
            aboutSectionType: '',
            aboutCustomizedDescription: '',
            showSpacesFollowed: true,
            showBadgesEarned: true,
            showMobileNumber: true,
            showOfficeNumber: false,
            showEmail: true,
            showSlackHandle: false,
            video: {},
            socialLinks: [],
            personalLinks: [],
          })
```